# True /False question based on quotient groups of $S_{n} $ and $A_{n} $.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

I am trying assignment questions of Abstract algebra and I need help in following True/ False question.

> Which one of following is true?
>
> 1. Every finite group is subgroup of $A_{n} $ for some $n\geq 1.$
> 2. Every finite group is quotient of $A_{n} $ for some $n\geq 1$.
> 3. No finite group is quotient of $S_{n} $ for  $n\geq 3.$

I think 2 can't be true as quotient  group of $A_{n} $ will also have even cardinality and Group can be of odd cardinality.

For 3 . I need to know about all quotient groups of $S_{n } $ which are $S_{n} $ and {0,1} and so $Z_{2} $ is an abelian group asked in 3 . Hope I am right!!

Can anyone please tell in detail on how I can prove 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. This is true. Every finite group is isomorphic to some subgroup of some $S_n$ and $S_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{n+2}$.
2. This is false. It follows from the fact that $A_n$ is simple if $n>4$.
3. The group $S_n$ itself is a quotient of $S_n$, for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Just curious: what’s this injection $S_n \rightarrow A_{n+2}$?

Comment: Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Relation_with_alternating_group): "$S_n$ can be embedded into $A_{n+2}$ by appending the transposition $(n+1,n+2)$ to all odd permutations..."

Comment: See $S_n$ as the group of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Let $\tau$ be the permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+2\}$ such that $\tau(k)=k$ if $k\leqslant n$, $\tau(n+1)=n+2$ and $\tau(n+2)=n+1$. Finally, define $\Psi(\sigma)=\sigma$ if $\sigma$ is even and $\Psi(\sigma)=\sigma\circ\tau$ otherwise.

Comment: Ah, very nice!!

Comment: I guess you can see it like this as well: there’s a canonical map $S_n \rigtarrow S_n \times S_n/A_n$ and then $S_n$ and $<(n+1 n+2)>$ are two commuting subgroups of $S_{n+2}$ so you can embed $S_n \times C_2 = S_n \times S_n/A_n$ into it. :)

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos can you please tell that whether my reasoning is correct for options 2 and 3 . I shall be really thankful to you for your comments.

Comment: Your answer to option 2 is wrong, since a finite group $G$ with an even number of elements can have quotients with an odd number of elements. For instance, $G/G$ has a single element. And I don't understand your answer to option 3.